# WPF: Image with Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I was wondering if anyone can help with two questions. Below is a canvas with a path, I have been looking at this code and am trying to work out what it is showing.

My questions are the Data in the path, what kind of data is it, it does not look like binary?

My second question is that I want to be able to create my own version of this data with a different image is this possible? Can I take another image get it raw data and use that instead of the data below.

```
<Canvas Width="48" Height="48" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 48,0L 48,48L 0,48L 0,0" x:Key="appbar_cloud_download">
        <Path Width="24" Height="13.0001" Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="18" Stretch="Fill"  Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" Data="F1 M 31,21C 33.7614,21 36,23.2386 36,26C 36,28.7614 33.7615,30.9999 30.9797,31L 24.5,31L 28,27L 26,27L 26,23L 23,23L 23,27L 21,27L 24.5,31L 14.5,31C 13.1193,31 12,29.8807 12,28.5C 12,27.2758 12.8799,26.2571 14.0417,26.0419L 14,25.5C 14,23.6206 15.4814,22.0871 17.3402,22.0035C 18.1629,19.6713 20.3863,18 23,18C 25.4816,18 27.6113,19.5065 28.5245,21.6549C 29.2543,21.2381 30.0994,21 31,21 Z " />
    </Canvas>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [path markup syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx). It's used for describing path geometries.

And yes you can create your own geometries. I recommend to use expression blend. You draw your  geometries there with the available tools (e.g. line, pencil) and export/copy paste the created path markup syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You are quite correct, it's not binary data, it's a markup language used to direct a pen, you can read up on the markup language [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx)

There is quite a nice tool for getting path data [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gavingear/archive/2007/02/15/intoducing-pathmaker-a-tool-for-creating-path-markup-for-wpf-e.aspx)